# Problems with background-image centered/fixed in IE8 and below

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, background-image

I published a website at: http://semep.com.br/Clientes

I'm having problems with IE8 and below the background-image property

### IE8

[image: background-image in IE8]

> Full image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRAHd.jpg

### IE9

[image: IE9 background-image]

> Full image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdvWw.jpg

**Both in IE9 as in any other browser, everything works perfectly!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use that:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='YOURBACKGROUND.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='YOURBACKGROUND.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

Comment: where is this code implemented?  in the CSS properties for that particular element?  Doesn't seem to work for me :(

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using :

```
background-position: center;
```

Use:

```
background-position-x: center;
background-position-y: 0;
```

Or:

```
background-position: center top;
```